# Xamarin.android invoke system Input via service

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to make a service that takes a string input from my Bluetooth device(this part is working) and invoke systems gesture events. The events should be recognized by other apps. I need to invoke

- Tap
- Doubletap
- Longtap
- Swip(left, right, up, down)

The Device should behave the same way it would as if I had tapped it manually. Thanks for your time.

Comment: By `invoke systems gesture events. The events should be recognized by other apps.`, Can you describe it in detail? Or is there any product which likes your requirement?

Comment: I basically want the device to react like I physically interacted with it. But the interaction comes from my Bluetooth device. So when I press a Button on my Bluetooth device I want a Tap gesture being fired whether I am in the menu, my custom app or a third party app.